# Multiple Resource server configuration in Spring security OAuth

Tags: oauth, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying use a single Auth server to access multiple resource servers from multiple clients.

I am trying to access two resource servers from same auth server and my configuration of resource servers goes as below.

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype") 
protected ResourceServerConfiguration resource1() {

    ResourceServerConfiguration resource = new ResourceServerConfiguration();
    resource.setConfigurers(Arrays.<ResourceServerConfigurer> asList(new ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID1).tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/greeting")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/users").hasRole("ADMIN");                
    }
}   
resource.setOrder(4);
    return resource;
}

@Bean
@Scope("prototype") 
protected ResourceServerConfiguration resource2() {
    ResourceServerConfiguration resource = new ResourceServerConfiguration();
    resource.setConfigurers(Arrays.<ResourceServerConfigurer> asList(new ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
            resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID2).tokenStore(tokenStore);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .csrf().disable()
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/welcome")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/users").hasRole("ADMIN");
        }
    }   
    resource.setOrder(5);
    return resource;
}
```

Since default order of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is 3,I have configured the Order of Resource servers as 4 and 5 respectively.

But the configured Beans are getting overridden and I can access the resource "/welcome" which has order 5 and if I try to access the resource "/greeting",I am getting the following error,

```
{  "timestamp": 1444400211270,  "status": 403,  "error": "Forbidden",  "message": "Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?",  "path": "/greeting"}
```

If I interchange the order between the resources,I can access the resource which has the highest value 5.

Note:I have two clients so that one can access RESOURCE1 and another can access RESOURCE2.

Please advice the things I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

From the Javadoc of `ResourceServerConfigurer`:

> Applications may provide multiple instances of this interface, and in
>   general (like with other Security configurers), if more than one
>   configures the same property, then the last one wins. The configurers
>   are sorted by `Order` before being applied.

So maybe put a `permitAll()` on the `/welcome` path in both configuration.