# Spring Security OAuth2: '#oauth2.xxx' expressions not evaluted with multiple RequestMatchers mapped to the same FilterChain

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

In a multi modules app I've defined 5 RequestMatchers mapped to the same FilterChain, like below:

```
@Configuration
public class Module1SecurityFilterChain extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
      http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy( STATELESS );
      http.requestMatchers().antMatchers( "/module1/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers( "/module1/resource").authenticated()
            .antMatchers( "/module1/test" ).access( "#oauth2.isClient()")
            .anyRequest().access( "#oauth2.hasScope('webclient')" );
   }
}
```

And module2:

```
@Configuration
public class Module2SecurityFilterChain extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
      http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy( STATELESS );
      http.requestMatchers().antMatchers( "/module2/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers( "/module2/resource").authenticated()
            .antMatchers( "/module2/test" ).access( "#oauth2.isClient()")
            .anyRequest().access( "#oauth2.hasScope('webclient')" );
   }
}
```

And enabled method security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true )
public class MethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

The problem is that all `#oauth2.xx` expressions are evaluated only for the 1st module requestmatcher `/module1/**` and ignored in others. When I authenticate a user and try to access to `/module1/test` the access is denied as expected whereas when accessing to `/module2/test` access is granted (it should also be denied).

Could someone explains me why and how to solve this? I know Spring Security isn't easy at all... 
Thanks again.

**EDIT** 
@Darren Forsythe (thanks for your comment)
The filter chains created are:

```
INFO | o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain | Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/oauth/token'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@f55a810b, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@85021903, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1d0744d1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2d15146a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@c38f3266, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@8f9bf85, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@74a71be5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@e4eb6cc, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@22f6b39a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@960c464f, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@f7a19dc5]
INFO | o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain | Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/module1/**'], Ant [pattern='/module2/**'], Ant [pattern='/module3/**'], Ant [pattern='/module4/**'], Ant [pattern='/module5/**'], Ant [pattern='/module6/**']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@38ef2427, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@a26ff7af, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5344e710, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@da0534c8, org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter@2956c7ab, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5682f610, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@f4cbf7a4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@d1b1395a, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@d352f8ab, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@9bb1d86, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@73c7a695]
INFO | o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain | Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1cc2056f, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@259d95db, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@de089e0b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@8b86b4c, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@96304ca8, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1d5b7e4b, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@bd586b4d, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7cff2571]
```

As you can see, all module's urls are mapped to the same filter chain with this list of filters:

```
Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

What I don't understand is why for the other modules the `#oauth2.xx` expression is not evaluated since the FilterChain is the same?

Comment: I can't remember the answer exactly but I believe it will be due to to the fact while you're specifying paths the security filter chain will be created with an Any matcher and all requests will drop into the first chain. 

If you check startup logs when the filter chains are created you should see two being created, both will be any matcher and contain the separate filters. There's a method you need to set first in the http security to specify what requests the filter is applicable for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Resource server configuration in Spring security OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33050883/multiple-resource-server-configuration-in-spring-security-oauth)

Comment: @akuma8 To make more clear: You override property `.authorizeRequests()` in your second configuration.

Comment: @akuma8 I found another question containg a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894809/spring-security-oauth2-multiple-resourceserverconfiguration-not-working You could use that question as duplicate target.

Comment: @dur I misspoke, when I said "all resources are protected", I meant by default a user can't access any resource before getting an access token. But when he/she gets a token, he/she is able to access all resources in other modules even resources that only clients should be granted, here `#oauth2.isClient()`

Comment: @akuma8 No, it isn't a separate configuration, you only use separate configurers.

Comment: @dur I mean what does it change if the 2nd configuration overrides the 1st one since it’s the same security rule?

Comment: @akuma8 It overrides `.authorizeRequests()`. It is not the same for both configurer.

Comment: @akuma8, the reason that the other matchers aren't getting picked up is because Spring Security uses a "catcher's mit" analogy when collecting matchers. So, for example, if I did `.anyRequest().authenticated().antMatchers("/module2/resource").permitAll()` then the `/module2/resource1` would be ignored because `anyRequest()` is a "bigger" catcher's mit. Since Spring Security OAuth simply calls these configuerers in sequence on the same `HttpSecurity` object, calling `anyRequest` in module one will override any `antMatcher` in subsequent modules.

Comment: @jzheaux You absolutely right. How do you know that? I took a look at the doc and did'nt see that, where can I find the order of "`catcher's mit`"? Spring Security makes me crazy!

Comment: @akuma8, it's here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authorize-requests where it says that the matchers are processed in order of declaration. It's a bit subtle, though. I've added a ticket to Spring Security to fail fast when something like this happens: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6359

Comment: @jzheaux Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Request matchers (specified in `antMatchers`, `anyRequest`, etc.) are processed by the filter chain in the order they are specified. Because multiple `ResourceServiceConfiguredAdapter` instances simply configure off of the same instance of `HttpSecurity`, the matchers are processed something like this for each one of your requests:

```
if (uri == "/module1/resource") {
    // ...
} else if (uri == "/module1/test") { 
    // ...
} else if (true) { // anyRequest
    // ...
} else if (uri = "/module2/resource") {
    // ...
} else if (uri = "/module2/test") {
    // ...
}
```

As you can see, the last two if conditions would never get hit.

Here are two things you can consider:

### Replace `anyRequest()`

`anyRequest` is usually very handy; however, in this case, you don't actually mean "any request" since you are trying to narrow the scope to certain module paths. You might instead do:

```
http
    .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/module2/**")
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/module2/resource").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/module2/test").access( "#oauth2.isClient()")
        .antMatchers("/module2/**").access( "#oauth2.hasScope('webclient')" );
```

That way, the module doesn't overreach and try and specify behavior that maybe it doesn't know about.

Truthfully, it is typically harmless to call `anyRequest` since you are already narrowing the scope of the filter chain already with `requestMatchers`. But, because you are composing a single `HttpSecurity` with multiple adapters, there is this hidden complexity.

### `oauth2ResourceServer()` - Spring Security 5.1+

If you are on [Spring Security 5.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2resourceserver), then there is actually support built into `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` natively, so you don't need to use `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` anymore, at least for JWT-encoded tokens at this point. This is also nice because two `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`s are treated as separate filter chains.

Depending on the OAuth 2.0 features you need, you may be able to do that instead:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Module1Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/module1/**")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/module1/resource").authenticated()
                .anyRequest.hasRole("SCOPE_webclient")
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();
    }
}
```

This is an active area of development for Spring Security right now - porting features over into `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`; so definitely reach out with your specific use case to make sure that it gets prioritized if it isn't already in place.

Comment: Thanks for these details, I use Spring Security 5.1.2 and 2.3.4 for OAuth2. You right to merge the OAuth2's configuration part in the Spring Security Core because it's too cumbersome to have 2 configurations. I often don't know which takes precedence between `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` vs `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter `. I absolutely didn't know  the `oauth2ResourceServer()` method. In all cases Spring Security will remain my worst nightmare ^^, I hope fully understanding how it works. Thanks again

Comment: @akuma8 Depending on which OAuth 2.0 features you need, you do not need to include OAuth2 2.3.4 (the dependency that includes `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`), see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix. Spring Security 5.1 includes OAuth2 natively and is introducing new OAuth 2.0 features with each release (5.2 is around the corner). Regarding your frustration, how would you like to see Spring Security change? I'd invite you to open tickets with your suggestions: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/new